# If statement Default value in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, if-statement

In MS Access table design, I am trying to do a simple default value for a column `Comment` which is dependent on column `Name`, example: if Column `Name` is = `Damian` column `Comment` should be equal to `Dames` I have tried this: `IIf([Name] Like Damian,"Dames","Nothing")` but I keep getting error messages that database doesn't recognize column Name, ane this statement was entered in the default value area

Comment: Is this Excel or Access? You have it tagged as Excel with Excel as the title, and yet you are using Access syntax.

Comment: So sorry, the stress seems to getting to me, yes it is Access

Answer (score 2):

In MS Access table design, a field's Default Value property can not reference another field in that table ... or any other table.

Unfortunately, the error message you get when you try does not make that point clear ...

*"The database engine does not recognize either the field <name> in a validation expression, or the default value in the table <name>. (Error 3344)"*

You will need to find another way to accomplish your goal.

Comment: The Default Value applies only at the instant a new record is created.  At that moment, nothing has yet been entered into the `Name` field, so the Default Value of `Comment` can not be based on the value of `Name` ... because there's nothing there to base it on.

Comment: Ok totally understood